# javascript number greater than number not return correct result

Tags: javascript

in this below code i want to say IF `data.transferMoney` greater than `results[0].money` THEN return false ELSE return true, but it doesn't return correct result

```
if (Number(results[0].money) < Number(data.transferMoney))
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

or this code:

```
if (parseInt(results[0].money) < parseInt(data.transferMoney))
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

`results[0].money` and `data.transferMoney` are string

`results[0].money` is 180476 and `data.transferMoney` is 12

Comment: share value of `data` and `result`

Comment: I just mention that you can return `boolean` directly: `return parseInt(results[0].money) >= parseInt(data.transferMoney)`

Comment: @madox2 return is sample, i need more that that to handle

Comment: @tux-world : can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet with dummy values

Comment: your code returns true; if you're getting false, then your data is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Josh `results[0].money` is 180476 and `data.transferMoney` is 12, then i think  `results[0].money` greater than `data.transferMoney`, is it incorrect?

Comment: Yes, `results[0].money` is greater than `data.transferMoney`, so the `else` clause will execute, thus your function will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Your data is bad. The following snippet meets your requirements and works as expected. I also added an isNaN check to meet a bad data requirement that you might want to check out in your own code.

```js
var results = [{money: '180476'}];
var data = {transferMoney: '12'};

if(isNaN(results[0].money) || isNaN(data.transferMoney))
   alert('bad data');

if (Number(results[0].money) < Number(data.transferMoney))
    alert('false');
else
    alert('true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you sholdn't never have to parse numbers in response from your own server. And that's what you are doing. AN dont parseInt when you are dealing with money.

What if there is a return from server that looks loke that: '10000000$ is way to much, you don't have that sum on account!'

Lets' see

```
parseInt('10000000$ is way to much, you dont have that sum on account!')
//1000000
```

I'd rather advise to compare number from user input directly with serverside number. This case if somthing on server ever goes wrong - you wont tell your users lie about their accounts :)